# Oracle RESTful Query with OAuth2 authorization - How to get the User belonging to the token?

Tags: oracle, rest, oauth

We're developing an Oracle database based RESTful webservice and we're using OAuth2 code protocol flow to issue Bearer tokens for querying with OAuth2 Bearer Authorization.

The Authorization itself works fine, but when we perform a RESTful query, we need to know which user is currently associated with the token.

We initially tried with the "APEX_UTIL.GET_CURRENT_USER_ID", but it doesn't return a value when queried from via OAuth2 authorized RESTful query.

Do you have any ideas on how I could grab the current user in that scenario?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the solution, it's actually pretty simple:
Just use the property: ":current_user
;)